# if "n" is found in row display then offset 0

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have been playing around to display 0 in a cell. If cell n equals to or more than 3 "n"'s found within a row then show 0 in cell m else show total. I have been attempting to achieve this with an if statement but it always shows false. Im not having any luck on this. any help
much appreciated.

[image: illstration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"n")>=3,0,SUM(A1:D1))
```

[image]

Comment: yes @simoco that is what I am looking for. I understood the logic but did not know how to articulate it in excel. Muchas Gracias

Comment: I did forget sorry : )